# KendoUI for Ipad

Tags: visual-studio-2010, kendo-ui

I want to create an App that contains student profiles targeting tablette with KendoUI.
The app will have the native look and feel (not website).
Can i create the app with ASPX pages or should i necessarily use .HTML pages?
What is the best practices?

Comment: Not really sure what ASPX is, but if you want to make an iPad app  [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) might  be interesting if you choose HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The final result (no matter what web framework you use) is always HTML. Kendo UI is a client-side framework  which means that you can use KendoUI with ASPX if you want or with clean HTML pages. It is up to the developer and there are no best practices.

However I would say +1 for the ASP.NET MVC framework :).